# Create a program that will ask the user to input the number of elements and enter the values for each element, then returns the sum of all the values

Tags: python, arrays, list, range

Create a program that will ask the user to input the number of elements and enter the values for each element, then returns the sum of all the values.[image]

My initial program:

```
num_ele = 0


#Create a program that will ask the user to input the number of elements 
#enter the values for each element then returns the sum of all the values

num_ele = int(input("Enter the number of elements: "))
for i in range(num_ele):
    print("Enter value:", int(i + 1))
total = int(sum(range(num_ele + 1)))
print("Sum of all elements in given list is : ", int(total))
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this! @Guy

1. I was wondering what I should input in order to display "Enter value: " depending on the number of elements inputted. 

2. How to convert print(Enter value:", int(i+1)) into an input function again.

Sample expected outputs are shown in an image above.

Comment: be sure to edit you question to include the clarification! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
num_ele = 0


#Create a program that will ask the user to input the number of elements 
#enter the values for each element then returns the sum of all the values

num_ele = int(input("Enter the number of elements: "))
total = 0
for i in range(num_ele):
    val = int( input(f"Enter value: {int(i + 1)}" ))
    total += val
print("Sum of all elements in given list is : ", float(total))
```

Output:

```
Enter the number of elements:  5
Enter value: 1 5
Enter value: 2 2
Enter value: 3 3
Enter value: 4 6
Enter value: 5 2
Sum of all elements in given list is :  18.0
```

Comment: Thanks for this but this is for a different expected output.

Comment: What is your expected output? The answer in based on your question

Comment: The sample expected outputs are shown in a picture above, "My initial program".

Comment: @KuroshSigariAvendano If the difference you see is in the Enter value line
`int( input(f"Enter value: " ))`. Simply remove the i+1 block. But @Will answer is totally valid. Please clarify your question.